# How large were the show-breads based on the measurements of Leviticus 24:5?

Tags: leviticus

I have a couple of question regarding the show-bread. I've done some research on this and it seems that by my calculations the loaves would have been huge. Were the leavened? I don't think the recipe says whether they should be flat or raised; what would be the default?

And what did the show-breads show?

> Lev 24:5  And thou shalt take fine wheaten flour, and bake twelve
>   cakes thereof; each cake shall be of two tenths.  Lev 24:6  And thou
>   shalt set them in two rows, six in a row, upon the pure table before
>   Jehovah.

By the way, I do have a theory as to why they seem to be so big (20 lbs of flour each?) but I've never seen any commentary on the size of them to compare notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received this response from a rabbi at chabad.org:

> The Talmud in Menachos gives us its measurements. Since there is doubt
>   as to what is exactly an Issaron in mondern measurements, you'll
>   notice various opinions.
>
> The Stei Halachem was two loaves of bread made from two Esronim of
>   fine wheat flour (approximately 4.32, 4.98 or 8.64 liters) which was
>   then mixed with Se'or (sourdough) causing them to rise.
>
> Each loaf is seven Tefachim long (approximately 53.2, 56 or 67.2 cm)
>   and four Tefachim wide (30.4, 32 or 38.4 cm); the corners of the
>   loaves project upward to a height of four Etzba'os

Comment: In the above, "tefach" is a hand's breadth, "etsba" is a finger's breadth.